# Wowza bandwidth used in cPanel?

Tags: cpanel

How to view or compute or add, bandwidth used in wowza stream port 1935 in user account in cPanel?

If you have a cPanel + Wowza installation will find this same difficult. The Wowza uses port 1935 to display streaming videos and cPanel does not monitoring this port by default. That way later in the month the user may have used 5Gb streaming by Wowza on port 1935 and cPanel will display the report with 3Gb only computing access the standard ports cPanel by example: http (80), ftp (21) pop (110), SMTP (587).
My question is: How to add port 1935, used by the Wowza streaming videos, monitoring by cPanel too.
If you can set this bandhwith use, the user is limited to the plan contracted in cPanel normally.

Comment: Can you expand upon this any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't from within cPanel. cPanel only offers bandwidth monitoring on certain fixed ports:
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Bandwidth

- Http — Web traffic.
- Pop3 — Email that your accounts received.
- Imap — Email that your accounts received.
- Ftp — File transfers.
- Smtp  — Email that your accounts sent.
- All

You would need to do it from the underlying operating system.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you now how or any idea how can i do this control?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible at current to monitor the bandwidth directly via cPanel however there is a module for Wowza which I believe does exactly what you need.

[How to monitor bandwidth of published streams (ModuleLimitPublishedStreamBandwidth)](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?231-Module-Collection-ModuleLimitPublishedStreamBandwidth)

The link below will explain how to configure modules.

[Configure modules](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?625-How-to-get-started-as-a-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-Manager-administrator#configModules)